# How do I increment a variable?

Tags: vimscript

My question might be silly since I'm a new vimscript user.

I need to define a variable as follows:

```
let foo = 1
"Implementing foo
:echo foo
```

Without success, I tried to increment my variable with the following syntaxes:

```
foo = foo + 1
++foo
foo++
foo+=1
```

I might miss something quite obvious, but I can't figure what.

I know about the `<C-a>` shortcut but I'm searching for a syntactical way of doing things.

Comment: You still need to use the `:let` command, so either `:let foo = foo + 1` or `:let foo += 1` will work. You don't need the `:` if you're in a vimscript, only when typing commands from inside Vim itself.

Comment: The `<C-a>` key binding is a Normal mode command, so it's not really related to Vim variables. It acts on the buffer contents instead.

Comment: If you want to learn Vimscript, my recommendation is the excellent ["Learn Vimscript the Hard Way"](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) by Steve Losh.

Answer (score 9):

In vim script, everything has to be an ex (`:`) command. Thus, the way vim distinguishes a command named `foo` and changes to the variable `foo` is the `let` command:

```
let foo += 1
```

This is not so in vim9script, where

```
foo += 1
```

works fine, and so does `++foo` (but not (yet) in an expression).